# How to call the 'collection' method on a 'Database' object when the method doesn't exists

Tags: android, python, mongodb, arduino

I am trying to connect a Python program through an Arduino to a MongoDB database, however, I keep running into:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. 
If you meant to call the 'collection' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

(This is my first post, excuse any bad formatting and let me know if more info is needed to understand the issue)

The program used to be connected to a firebase database and the code didn't have any issues then. When I made the new database in MongoDB, I named the collections the same thing.

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@smartcontainer-jp0au.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority") #connects to MongoDB
db = client.get_database('SmartContainerDemo') #connects to database
users_ref = db.collection(u'devices') #connects to collection (I believe error is here)

def update_device(device_num, readingGram, lastRead):
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'devices').document(u'device' + str(device_num))
    doc_ref.set({u'readingGram': readingGram, u'lastRead': lastRead})
```

I expect to have my database updated automatically when weight is put onto a scale, but instead, I am getting:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'collection' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Comment: Dear please have a look on question guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as you need lot of formatting issues.

Comment: I have figured out the collection issue, but am running into a pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed: smartcontainer-shard-00-00-jp0au.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host,SSL handshake failed: smartcontainer-shard-00-02-jp0au.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host,SSL handshake failed: smartcontainer-shard-00-01-jp0au.mongodb.net:27017: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
now

Answer (score 0):

Check out documentation:  http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database

Database object indeed does not have collection() method as the error suggests, you need to use get_collection().

Comment: So I replaced with get_collection() but it still runs into the same error

Comment: @nan-gib which version of pymongo are you using? Also I don't think you need to write collection name like this: " u'devices' ", simply use 'devices' (although I doubt it's the source of your problem).